# Where can I find the country number in magento?

Tags: magento, country, country-codes

I've read a lot about countrycodes in Magento, but now my question is; where can I find country numbers in Magento? Does this exist? I'm no programmer so I can not edit some code.

We recieved an order from Austria, but somehow Magento sends the number "00" (Holland) to our server where this must be "14" (Austria) as shipping code.
The package was returned to us because this address did not (of course) exist in Holland.

Answer (score 0):

Magento returns standard country codes.  You can find the list here;

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/iso3166/

In any of your template files you can echo the current stores country code with this;

```
$countryCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/default');
echo $countryCode;
```